# Javascript code that should allow me to trigger a click event

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I got a function in javascript that should enable the enter button on my keyboard to trigger a mouse click event. The code works fine in Microsoft Edge, but apparently it does not work in Google Chrome.

In the program the code should allow me to enter password and the click enter to trigger the log in click event.

The javascript code:

```
function button_click(objTextBox, objBtnID) {
if (window.event.keyCode == 13) {
    document.getElementById(objBtnID).focus();
    document.getElementById(objBtnID).click();
}}
```

And in aspx.cs:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Password.Attributes.Add("onkeypress", "button_click(this,'" + LogIn.ClientID + "')");
    }
```

Where "Password" is the text box and "LogIn" is the button.

Comment: "It does not work" is not a useful description. Did you get any errors in the console?

Comment: It redirects me to another click event

Comment: Also you don't really need to trigger a click event. Either call `submit()` on your form element, or if doing ajax/validation just call the function that does that